# Can a toilet vent be upstream?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain-waste-vent

I am relocating the bathroom door and the toilet vent is right in the middle of the new opening. I want to put the vent in the wall behind the toilet which will be upstream of the toilet. Will this work? The vent is currently about 6 feet in front of the toilet. The shower drain will be connected into the 3" toilet pipe about 3 feet downstream of the toilet.

The image below is what I'm hoping to do, with two different ways to handle the vent connection.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are within 6' so it would be allowed in my state.

Comment: Would the section between the toilet & vertical vent stack just be horizontal (1/4 slope)? Or does it have to be elevated or somehow prevent solids from blocking the vent?

Comment: Solids won’t be trying to go up the vent as air will be assisting in either case but in most cases you only have ~1foot so it doesn’t matter.

Answer (score -1):

No on the first proposal.  toilets need a wye and 1/8 or a long sweep closet 90.  Solids need help being directed.  the second is fine.  Vent to not be horizontal.  Vertical or 45*

Comment: Solids will not be passing through a 90 in either scenario

Comment: Hello, again. This is interesting, but a bit hard to understand for most non-professionals. Would  you add a bit more info? Thanks.

Comment: Problem is with the first side view.  the venting will work, but what you've shown is in effect a sanitary tee on the transition to the horizontal.  Not allowed.  Too abrupt.  That needs a more gradual transition.  Wye and 1/8 or a closet bend with a venting wye just downstream, as you did in option #2.     Option #2:  Make sure the 3x2 wye is not flat in its back.  the vent leg should be at a 45* if it is a full dry vent so it stays above the solids and avoids clogs